# Infinit login loop if I change the password for an user

Tags: login, password, users

If I change the password for an user from an admin account (as admin), I can no more login due to an infinite login loop.
If I change again using to the old password, everything is OK again.
How could I change the password still being able to login?
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Is the user home encrypted?

Comment: If I run ls -A /home, there is a .ecryptfs file, so it seems that it is encrypted.

Comment: Does changing the user's password from within that user's account work, then?

Comment: If home is encrypted you have to change the password graphically as the user. This prevents root from accessing the encrypted data by changing the password on the command line as you can see.

Comment: I confirm that this solved the problem